# Is there any nuance between "is one island" and "is an island"?

Tags: meaning, articles

> Hainan is __ island, isn't it?
>
> A. the
>
> B. one
>
> C. a
>
> D. an

The answer is B. But I think D is also ok.

What is the nuance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that either 'an' or 'one' could be used, depending on the context. Unfortunately, you don't have any context.

"Hainan is *an* island" is probably the expected answer. The statement tells us what kind of place Hainan is - an island, surrounded by water, as opposed to a peninsula or an enclave.

Using the number *one* instead of the indefinite article places the emphasis of your statement on the number. "Hainan is *one* island" would be used if your aim was to point out that it is a single island as opposed to an archipelago, which is a place comprised of numerous islands.

Comment: I might see a slightly different idea, maybe depending on spoken emphasis, in saying that Ireland, or Cyprus, 'is one island'.

Answer (score 0):

The emphasis is different here. "One" focuses on the fact that Hainan is a province composed of a single island. Rather than two or more islands. The latter states that Hainan is an island. What is the context?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).